# Measuring time of a SQL-Query, send by PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, timing

I try to measure how much time it takes for the PDO element to send a query and retrieve an answer.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=dbname;host=dbhost;charset=utf8', "username", "password");

$timing = -microtime(true);

    $query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID = 1');
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetch();

var_dump($timing + microtime(true));
```

The result should be something around 0.0012 seconds, at least that's what phpmyadmin shows as duration time. But the result is always:

```
float(0)
```

Is there some sort of rounding issue, I'm not aware of?

- OS : WindowsXP
- PHP : 5.4.16
- MySQL : 5.1.51
- Server : Apache 2.4.4

Comment: What values is `microtime()` returning in each call?

Comment: They are exactly the same, so it isn't a rounding issue. But i don't think that the PDO element is faster then a microsecond ^^

Answer (score 2):

no better code than that from the manual

```
$time_start = microtime(true);

//your code

$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "it took $time seconds\n";
```

Comment: It should work,as well as my interpretation. But the result is always the same.

Comment: microtime gives you microseconds, not seconds

Comment: @erdomester your wrong or the manual is wrong, guess which: http://codepad.viper-7.com/VuoZYO